# Getting write request value from NSArray with Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have a method here:

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests
{
    NSLog(@"PERIPHERAL: peripheralManager:%@ didReceiveWriteRequests:%@", peripheral, requests);
    NSString * result = [[requests valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    _label.text = result;
}
```

I receive the write request in an `NSArray`. Right now I am just converting the full array into a string and outputting the string into a text box. To make sure everything is set up correctly. It indeed is working, but I do not want the full array listed but just the value alone stored in a `NSString`.

I want this in a string:

> Test

Not this:

> CBATTRequest: 0x1702240 Central = , Characteristic = , Offset = 0, Value = test

This should be easy to accomplish and I am possibly just brain dead from a long day. How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: Which value?  The description of the first element?  Just retrieve the first element and then get its description property. Once you have the string, convert it to NSData - see the NSString reference

Comment: Okay I am able to seperate the value now. But I am stuck with <54657374> instead of the sent "Test" I assume it is encoded somehow. Any experience decoding this?

Comment: Those are the ascii values of "Test", so it looks right to me - those are the bytes you need to send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider that `requests` is an array of `CBATTRequest`s, which have a `value` property containing an `NSData` object representing the data being written.

If you want one string representing all of the values, you need to iterate over `requests` and convert each of these `NSData` values to `NSString` and concatenate them. If I'm understanding your question correctly, this should be what you're looking for.

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests {

    NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (CBATTRequest *request in requests) {
        NSString *stringValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request value] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        if (stringValue) {
            [output appendString:stringValue];
        }
    }

    _label.text = output.copy;
}
```

As a note, updating to Xcode 7 would help make this more clear, since the `requests` parameter of `-peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests:` has updated to use Objective-C generics, and now has the type `NSArray<CBATTRequest *> *`.